# ByteArrayOutputStream vs. CharBuffer with CharSet

Tags: java, nio

I am just trying to avoid some large array copies(byte[] arrays).

```
I have a String of size n
I have a byte[] of size m
```

I am using ISO-8859-1 for the String.  I would very much like to write the String to byte[0] to byte[n-1] positions in this array, and then for the byte[], I will just System.arrayCopy the bytes into the array.

In looking at ByteArrayOutputStream, it is synchronized which I don't need and looking at byteBuffer.asCharBuffer(), I can't seem to supply the CharSet which I would prefer to always be explicit.

How can the above be achieved?

Also, I just found out byteBuffer.asCharBuffer assumes incorrectly that each char occupies two bytes which is not the case for ascii or ISO-8859-1 so CharBuffer in that regard is not working out too well.

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common way for writing the encoding the strings is [CharsetEncoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html). I believe it fits into this scenario too:

```
encoder = StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1.newEncoder();
ByteBuffer result = encoder.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(inputString));
// do whatever you want with result...
```